# Change the system environment variables permanently with java

Tags: java, environment-variables

When the JVM starts it gets a copy of the environment variables from the underlying operating system. Then in our java code, we can modify that copy of the environment variables. In java is there any way that we can change the original set of environment variables? I mean changing the system-level environment variables permanently?

Comment: No. And now I have to type enough to post my **comment**.

Comment: I think you cannot; what map of environment variables you see in Java is copied from the environment and changes won't be reflected back. And even if they were, it would only be seen by child processes of your Java process, to which you could pass arguments much easier by standard Java means. You cold of course modify the way variables are set, like editing the shell startup files, but that is tricky (which shell, which file?) and messy (why should any other program the user runs have to suffer the fallout from your program?).